# Using a exact match regex in contains method

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where each row contains a column that has words separated by commas. For example:
word1, word2, word3, word11

I am trying to return rows of the dataframe that contain "word1" but if I try `contains("word1")`, then it will return rows that have "word11" which is fine when "word1" is also in this row but not fine when "word1" is not in this row.

I believe a regex might be the way to go but I'm not familiar with them and after some research I am still having difficulty solving this.

Comment: Please, could you be more specific? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to enclose your word in [word boundaries `\b`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['word11,word2', 'wword1,word2', 'word3,word1', 'word1,word2', 'word0,word1,word2']})
df.col1.str.contains(r'\bword1\b')
```

Result:

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
```